# Does "cin" reset variable to some default value if input type differs from destination type?

Tags: c++, cin

I have an issue with behavior of "cin" (I do not understand).  My IDE is Netbeans under Windows OS (with Cygwin).

Here's a code example:

```
int main()
{
    int temp = -1;
    std::cin >> temp;    // here user enters string of characters (string) or a single character

    if (temp == 0)
        std::cout << "temp = " << temp << ".\n";
    if (temp == -1)
        std::cout << "temp = " << temp << ".\n";

    return 0;
}
```

This code shows message **temp = 0** if I enter some sort of a character/string of characters. It's like there is conversion of `char` to `int` and conversion always ending by value **0**.

Thank you if you can explain this behavior.

Comment: The input that `std::cin` reads is a stream of text. Beyond that, it does not have a type. The extractor (`operator>>`) **converts** that text into a value of the appropriate type if it can.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is expected behavior of [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt); since C++11 if extraction fails, the variable will be set to 0. Before C++11, the variable won't be modified then its original value remains.

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is
>   expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.   (until C++11)
>
> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If
>   extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in
>   value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min()
>   is written and failbit flag is set. (since C++11)

Comment: If no characters could be read then the value is unchanged; the setting 0 only happens on conversion failure

Comment: Just for information: I've used `std::cin.fail()` to check if there a *failbit* set.

Answer (score 4):

If the read fails `operator>>` will set the value to zero ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)):

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set.